# Create Google Spreadsheet programmatically PHP

Tags: php, laravel, api, google-sheets

I need to export some data in Google Spreadsheet. I have my API set up and working, I'm using laravel-google-sheets API to read and update existing spreadsheet. I can indeed read and update data, or add new sheets like this:

```
public function export(Request $request){
    $user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
    $title = "Test";
    $values1 = [
        ['id', 'name', 'mail'],
        ['1', 'name1', 'mail1'],
        ['2', 'name1', 'mail2'],
        ['3', 'name3', 'mail33']
    ];
    
    $token = [
        'access_token'  => $user->token,
        'refresh_token' => $user->refreshToken,
        'expires_in'    => $user->expiresIn
    ];

    $values = Sheets::setAccessToken($token)->spreadsheet('1VBkkUZkA79901CVssP1uwLF1oE9d69S502x9X_R0kw4')->sheet('Sheet1')->all();
    Sheets::spreadsheet('1VBkkUZkA79901CVssP1uwLF1oE9d69S502x9X_R0kw4')->addSheet($title);
    Sheets::sheet($title)->update($values1);
}
```

In this code I'm adding a new sheet and inserting data, but I have to pass spreadsheet id manually and also share it from google docs to my API credentials. The problem is, if I have a single spreadsheet for every user, all exported data will be visible to other users as well. I tried to create spreadsheet like this:

```
Sheets::spreadsheet();
```

But it did not help. Is it possible to create spreadsheets programmatically and how do I do this?

Comment: I think you can just [create a file using the Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/create-file) where you need it and then use the ID of that.

Comment: When you want to achieve your goal using your php script, as one of several methods, how about using the create method of Sheets API? In this case, you might be able to use the access token without changing the scopes. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/create#php By the way, in your question, the tag of `google-apps-script` is included. Do you want to achieve your goal using `google-apps-script`?